# Throwing error while saving multiple oneToMany Entity relations in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am having an entity class which has two Entity class with one to many relationship. and there is one root parent entity which has ID variable which is being extended by all the entity. When i am trying to save MessagingEnablerCfg entity without initializing it's member variable(messagingProfiles and messagingSessions). it is getting saved. but if i will try to initialize the these set variable. it is throwing following error while doing save or update operation:

**Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Field 'messagingProfiles_id' doesn't have a default value**

**Note:** if there is only one variable(either messagingProfiles or messagingSessions) in the MessagingEnablerCfg entity then it will work fine for saving or updating. 
i feel it is weird but right now it is a big trouble for me.

Please find the below Entity class

```
@Entity
//@Indexed
@Proxy(lazy=false)
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = Visibility.ANY, getterVisibility = Visibility.NONE, setterVisibility = Visibility.NONE)
public class MessagingConfigEntity{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    private String id;
    //@Override
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

another Entity class is:

```
@Entity
//@Indexed
@Proxy(lazy=false)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = Visibility.ANY, getterVisibility = Visibility.NONE, setterVisibility = Visibility.NONE)
public class MessagingEnablerCfg extends MessagingConfigEntity {        
    private String serviceName; 
    @OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
    private Set<MessagingProfileCfg> messagingProfiles = new HashSet<>();

    //@OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
    private Set<MessagingSessionCfg> messagingSessions  = new HashSet<>();

    public MessagingEnablerCfg(){

    }
    public MessagingEnablerCfg(String service){
        this.serviceName = service;
    }
    public String getServiceName() {
        return serviceName;
    }
    public void setServiceName(String serviceName) {
        this.serviceName = serviceName;
    }
    public Set<MessagingSessionCfg> getMessagingSessions() {
        return messagingSessions;
    }
    public void setMessagingSessions(Set<MessagingSessionCfg> messagingSessions) 
   {
        this.messagingSessions = messagingSessions;
    }
    public Set<MessagingProfileCfg> getMessagingProfiles() {
        return messagingProfiles;
    }
    public void setMessagingProfiles(Set<MessagingProfileCfg> messagingProfiles) 
    {
        this.messagingProfiles = messagingProfiles;
    }
    public void addSession(MessagingSessionCfg session){
        messagingSessions.add(session);

    }
    public void addProfile(MessagingProfileCfg profile){
        messagingProfiles.add(profile); 
    }
}
```

Another Child class is:

```
@Entity
//@Indexed
@Proxy(lazy = false)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = Visibility.ANY, getterVisibility = Visibility.NONE, setterVisibility = Visibility.NONE)
public class MessagingSessionCfg extends MessagingConfigEntity{

    private String sessionName;
    private String provider;

    public MessagingSessionCfg(){

    }
    public MessagingSessionCfg(String name,String provider){
        this.sessionName = name;
        this.provider = provider;
    }

    public String getSessionName() {
        return sessionName;
    }
    public void setSessionName(String sessionName) {
        this.sessionName = sessionName;
    }
    public String getProvider() {
        return provider;
    }
    public void setProvider(String provider) {
        this.provider = provider;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return "sessionName:"+sessionName+"  provider:"+provider;
    }
}
```

Ans last child entity is:

```
@Entity
//@Indexed
@Proxy(lazy=false)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = Visibility.ANY, getterVisibility = Visibility.NONE, setterVisibility = Visibility.NONE)
public class MessagingProfileCfg extends MessagingConfigEntity {

    private String profileId;
    private String sourceAddress;

    public MessagingProfileCfg(){

    }
    public MessagingProfileCfg(String profileId, String sourceAddress){
        this.profileId = profileId;
        this.sourceAddress = sourceAddress;
    }
    public String getProfileId() {
        return profileId;
    }
    public void setProfileId(String profileId) {
        this.profileId = profileId;
    }
    public String getSourceAddress() {
        return sourceAddress;
    }
    public void setSourceAddress(String sourceAddress) {
        this.sourceAddress = sourceAddress;
    }   
}
```